# Inconclusive second partial derivative test

Tags: multivariable-calculus

Consider the function $$f(x,y)=(x+y)^4$$ and determine whether $f$ has a maximum, a minimum or neither at the point $(0,0)$.

I thought I needed to use the second partial derivative test but how would I go about showing the point is neither a minimum nor a maximum if the test is inconclusive?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hint: what can you say about the fourth power of any real number?

Comment: It's always positive? I'm just stuck on how to go about proving that the point is neither a minimum nor a maximum.

Comment: The functions plot shows z=0 where y=-x

Comment: It's always $\ge 0$.  Surely you don't need a plot to see that $(x+y)^4 = 0$ when $y=-x$.  So if the function is always $\ge 0$, and it's equal to $0$ at $(0,0)$, is $(0,0)$ a minimum, a maximum, or neither?

Comment: Sorry, the question asked me to refer to the plot as well. I thought it was neither because z=0 along the line y=-x so it can't be an extrema?

Comment: What's the definition of an extremum?

Comment: It's a maximum or minimum. The point (0,0) is a minimum

Answer (score 0):

$$f(0, 0) = 0$$

What other values can $f$ assume?  For example, at $(1,1)$, $(-1, 1)$, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The Second Derivative Test in single-variable calculus and its analogue for multivariate functions, the second partial-derivative index or Hessian determinant, is of limited help for such functions built on sums of terms using power-functions with exponents larger than $ \ 2 \ . $

One problem we have with the function $ \ f(x,y) \  = \ (x+y)^4 \ $ is that its surface is a sort of "flat-bottomed trench", in which the origin lies on the line of symmetry $ \ y \  = \ -x \ $ , with $ \ f(x,-x) \ = \ 0 \ . $  There is not a critical *point*, but a *line* in the plane on which the second derivative of the function equals zero.

The other issue arises if we rotate the coordinate system in the plane by $ \ \frac{\pi}{4} \ $ , using $ \ u \ = \ x  +  y \ $ to write the function as $ \ f(u,0) \ = \ u^4 \ , \ f(0,v) \ = \ 0 \ \ . $  We already know from single-variable calculus that the second derivative will be $ \ 12u^2 \ , $ which is zero at $ \ u = 0 \ $ and positive otherwise (the curve is always "concave upwards").  It is the second-derivative *function* that tells us about the behavior of the function, rather than simply the value of the second derivative at the single point.

Here, the Hessian determinant is $ \ 12(x+y)^2  ·  12(x+y)^2 \  -  \ [12(x+y)^2]^2 \ = \ 0 \ , $ which is rather unhelpful.  We have at the origin what some authors call a *degenerate* critical point.  In such situations, we must further investigate the properties of the function and its first derivative in the hope of better understanding these points.